# Pourriez-vous me donner des variantes plus claires, plus élégantes et plus convaincantes du texte cité dans les détails?

Tags: reformulation

De quelle manière exprimeriez-vous ce texte pour le rendre plus agréable à lire?

Joanie a entamé un nouveau chapitre professionnel au Centre les Ruisseaux, plus près de son foyer. Jusqu'à récemment (vendredi passé) elle exerçait son métier au Centre St-Clotilde avec des adultes aux prises avec des troubles divers, mais dorénavant, elle se consacrera à une clientèle de jeunes, après avoir œuvré pour des cas lourds.

Comment: A part le mot "clientèle" qui n'est sans doute pas approprié (ce ne sont a priori pas des clients), ça me parait limpide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Joanie a entamé un nouveau chapitre professionnel au Centre les Ruisseaux, plus près de son foyer. Jusqu'à récemment (vendredi passé) elle exerçait son métier au Centre St-Clotilde avec des adultes aux prises avec des troubles divers, mais dorénavant, elle se consacrera à une clientèle de jeunes, après avoir œuvré pour des cas lourds.

- Joanie a entamé un nouveau chapitre de sa vie professionnelle au Centre *Les Ruisseaux*, qui se trouve plus près de son foyer. Jusqu'à récemment (vendredi passé) elle exerçait son métier  au centre *St-Clotilde*, s'occupant d'adultes aux prises avec des troubles divers, mais dorénavant, elle se consacrera à des patients jeunes*, après s'être concentrée sur des cas lourds.

Le terme idiomatique est « nouveau chapitre de sa vie X (professionnelle, de femme mariée, etc.) » : [chapitre](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nouveau%20chapitre%20de%20sa%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr).

<sup>*</sup> Suggéré par le commentaire de [user Guillaume](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52305/pourriez-vous-me-donner-des-variantes-plus-claires-plus-%c3%a9l%c3%a9gantes-et-plus-conva/52312#comment108555_52305)

Comment: Ici, qu’est-ce qui justifie l’utilisation d’un participe présent plutôt que d’un gérondif?

Comment: Ne peut-on pas y voir une forme de simultanéité entre l’action de le principale (exercer son métier) et l’action de la subordonnée (s’occuper d’adultes…) ?

Comment: « Ici, qu’est-ce qui justifie l’utilisation d’un participe présent plutôt que d’un gérondif? » : voilà une excellente question, que vous pourriez poser formellement, et à laquelle je ne peux pas répondre immédiatement, ni même, peut-être, de façon satisfaisante après une étude.

Comment: Il existe une notion de simultanéité dans les deux constructions, mais elle ne serait pas toujours présente avec le gérondif. Dans ce cas, je pense qu'il existe sans aucun doute une notion de simultanéité.

Answer (score 0):

> Joanie a entamé un nouveau chapitre professionnel au centre Les Ruisseaux, plus proche de son foyer. Vendredi dernier, elle exerçait encore au centre St-Clotilde avec des adultes souffrant de troubles divers. Dorénavant, elle se consacrera à de jeunes patients, s'éloignant de cas plus lourds.

Answer (score 0):

Joanie a décidé de donner un nouveau souffle à sa carrière en se dirigeant vers les eaux calmes du centre Les Ruisseaux. Elle quitte le tourbillon de complexité qu'elle a connu au centre St-Clotilde, où elle a consacré des années à aider les adultes à surmonter les obstacles de la vie. Maintenant, armée de son expérience et de sa détermination, elle se tourne vers les jeunes pour les aider à trouver leur chemin.
C'est un nouveau chapitre pour Joanie, qui s'est fixé pour objectif de devenir un phare de lumière pour ces jeunes en difficulté. Elle sait que la route ne sera pas facile, mais avec son sourire contagieux et sa passion pour aider les autres, elle est prête à relever ce nouveau défi. Joanie est déterminée à faire la différence dans la vie de ces jeunes et à leur montrer qu'ils peuvent surmonter tout obstacle qui se dressera sur leur chemin.